# Django CK Editor not loading on web hosting server but working in localhost

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Django ck-editor working in my local host but when host my website on web it's not working. Here is the console error which saying my JavaScript file not loading but I add static in head of my template but I didn't add `{%load static %}` in my local host template and it's working. Why it's not working in shared hosting??? why file is not loading?

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/atoms.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/polyfills.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/escape.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/playback.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/record.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
ckeditor.js:100 GET https://farhyn.com/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/image2/plugin.js?t=L4KA net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Comment: MattDMo I edited my question and added error text

Comment: Hello @boyenec Django does not handle static on server to server check this post for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/55400498/14457833